# Syntax error with elif

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I've written a little script which uses the if - elif construct. For some reason it just won't work.
The error code:

```
./lab4.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./lab4.sh: line 9: `elif [ $number -eq 2 ] then func2'
```

My actual code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#ask the user for a number between 1 and 3
#create some functions, write out the function number
echo "Enter a number between 1 and 3: "
read number

#which function should be called?
if [ $number -eq 1 ] then func1
elif [ $number -eq 2 ] then func2
elif [ $number -eq 3 ] then func3 fi

function func1 {
    echo "This message was displayed from the first function."
}

function func2 {
    echo "This message was displayed from the second function."
}

function func3 {
    echo "This message was displayed from the third function."
}
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Put a semicolon after `[ $number -eq 1 ];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return to a new line or use `;` before shell statement (`if`, `then`, `elif`, `fi` …).

You also have to declare your functions before use them.

```
#!/bin/bash
#ask the user for a number between 1 and 3
#create some functions, write out the function number
echo "Enter a number between 1 and 3: "
read number

function func1 {
    echo "This message was displayed from the first function."
}

function func2 {
    echo "This message was displayed from the second function."
}

function func3 {
    echo "This message was displayed from the third function."
}

#which function should be called?
if [ $number -eq 1 ]; then func1
elif [ $number -eq 2 ]; then func2
elif [ $number -eq 3 ]; then func3; fi
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually fixed that function thing but this if - elif construct was driving me crazy x)

Comment: Your welcome, thank to vote up.

Answer (score 2):

For such multiple `if/elif`s it's sometimes easier to use a `case` statement, like:

```
func1() { echo "func1"; }
func2() { echo "func2"; }
func3() { echo "func3"; }

while read -r -p 'Enter a number between 1 and 3:>' number
do
    case "$number" in
        1) func1 ; break ;;
        2) func2 ; break ;;
        3) func3 ; break ;;
        q) exit;;
        *) echo "Wrong input" >&2;; #error message
    esac
done
echo "end of loop"
```

Comment: don't use the `function` keyword. It is a *bashism*, the portable way to define a shell function is

```
funcname() {
}
```

and it is a bit shorter too... :)